# jQuery AJAX Post not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I cant not figure out why this script doesnt work. It has to do with something within the AJAX POST script/function. Right now, when I hit submit on my form it runs the php code on the same page. What it should do it is send the values of the form to project_ajax.php, then at page will return a var of success that will be true or false.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#didIt').hide();
    $('form[name=adminForm]').submit(function () {
        $.post('/project_ajax.php', {
            action: $('[name=action]').val(),
            pId: $('[name=pId]').val(),
            name: $('[name=name]').val(),
            url: $('[url=url]').val(),
            summary: ('[summary=summary]').val()
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('div#didIt').slideDown('slow');
            } else {
                alert('Failed SA!');
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Below is what the code for project_ajax.php...

```
if($_POST['action'] == "update") {
    //Prep the field for Query Entry!-----------------------------------
    $pId     = $_POST['pId'];
    $name    = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['name']));
    $status  = 1;
    $url     = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['url']));
    $tumb    = false; //False because I still need to make a script for it.
    $summary = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['summary']));
    $creater = $_SESSION['userId'];
    $created = date("Ymd");

    $q = "UPDATE " . DB_NAME . ".`projects` SET 
                    name    = '{$name}',
                    status  = '{$status}',
                    url     = '{$url}',
                    summary = '{$summary}',
                    creater = '{$creater}',
                    created = '{$created}'
              WHERE `projects`.`id` = {$pId}";
    $r = mysql_query($q, $connection);
    if ($r) {
        //Successful
        $data['success'] = true;
        $date['error']   = false;
        $date['message'] = "You are the Greatest!";

    } else {
        //Fail
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['error']   = true;
        $date['message'] = "You can't do it fool!";

    }

} else {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $date['error']   = true;
    $data['message'] = "You Failed Stupid!";
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Note: When load this page. The browser never really finsh loading. The the blue-ring on the title tab within IE8 spins as if the page never finsh loading.

Comment: Have you tested this in other browsers? It could be that it only fails in IE8. Also check if you get any JavaScript errors, which causes the code to fail (for example a syntax error, or something is undefined, etc). Check that the jQuery selector selects the right form.

Comment: Your PHP code looks like it is prone to SQL Injection attacks. Guess what happens if the user sends a `pId` with value `123; DROP TABLE some_table`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection for a description of the problem and several solutions for PHP

Comment: Well, I do believe my code is prone to SQL Injections. However I dont believe "pId" is one. Only because pId is a hidden value that is pulled from a database. Unless user can change hidden values? Can they change hidden values?

Comment: you assign a value from `$_POST` to `$pId` without escaping or typecasting it. If `projects.id` is an integer, you could cast it to an int (`$pId = (int) $_POST['pId'];`). But `$pId` isn't the only problem, so my suggestion is to move away from the `mysql_*` functions and use something like PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that supports prepared statements.

Comment: And to answer the question in your comment: yes, the user can change hidden values before sending them to your server. Basically, everything that comes from the user should be treated as potentially malicious data. It's an ugly world we live in...

Comment: Thanks. I must say I am not getting the PDO thing at all.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, regard "hidden" as nothing but a keyword which tells the browser to not display the form field (similar to "display:none;" in CSS). It's still very much accessible to manipulation.

Comment: piquadrat- If I could I'd vote up your comment as a paragon of tact and kindness :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
  summary: ('[summary=summary]').val()},
```

You have a missing $ which represents the jQuery function. Corrected:

```
summary: $('[summary=summary]').val()},
```

Because you have a Javascript error, the execution is terminated. Thus the loading takes forever.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed an error, but still that script doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Figured out what was wrong beside the missing "$"... The other problem was the '/' at "$.post('/project_ajax.php', {"